# List<T> is "better" then ICollection<T>? And why implement redundant interfaces?

Tags: c#

Q1: `List<T>` is "better" then `ICollection<T>`, more powerful. Why then in Code first tutorials they use `ICollection<T>`? Doesn't make any sense. `List<T>` can do everything that `ICollection<T>` and much more. Yes, I understand, its an interface and List is a class. But id doesn't answer the question. Why not use IList and not ICollection? And that is related to the following questions as well...

Q2: `List<T>` is defined as:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

where `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` (for example) is defined as

```
public interface IReadOnlyCollection<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

So, it already has `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable`.

Why then use **AGAIN** `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable` in `List<T>` definition?

Doesnt make any sense.

Q3: `IList<T>` is defined like this:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

I dont understand, if `List<T>` implements `IList<T>`,
when why use `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable` in `List<T>` definition again?

Wouldn't it be shorter to define List as:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>
```

where `IList<T>` already implements all the interfaces?

Why repeat all these interfaces again and again?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not about what's better, it's all about the functionality you need. Try not to look at it that way.

Comment: please elaborate... IList has all the functionality of ICollection. Why ICollection? It is not clear to me at all.

Comment: If you use List you will lose all performace buffs entityframework gives you

Comment: bto.rdz, I am not so sure about that, have you tried? measured the performance? why do you think so?

Comment: [`List<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/A.html#cf7f4095e4de7646) defined as: `public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>`

Comment: Jeff Mercado, lets say in addition to Add function I may want to use Sort as well. Then, why would I use an Interface that doesnt have this functionality instead of the one that does? Doesnt make sense.

Comment: Not really, List<T> is defined as I posted, at least according to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: These are all `contracts`... you usually don't expose a greater functionality than required, so that polymorphic behavior is easier to implement. Which is why we have `ICollection<T>` as well as `IList<T>`, and also the `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: @monstro yes I have, List will bring all records in database, Icollection wont

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1:**

A `List<T>` might be more 'powerfull' than an `ICollection<T>`, but it is less abstract.
If `ICollection<T>` exposes everything you need, then why would you specify that he has to use a `List<T>` and thereby limit the user of your interface / method / whatever and constrain him that he has to use a `List<T>`?

The user of your class / interface might not use a `List<T>` but a `HashedSet<T>` for instance, which is also an `ICollection<T`>, but not a `List<T>`.
If he wants to pass his HashedSet to your method, that would mean he has to convert his set to a list, if you define that your method should accept a List instead of an `ICollection<T>`.

An ICollection is less specific than a List, which means that as soon as a type implements ICollection, that type can be consumed by your method.
Offcourse you can only do this when an ICollection specifies all the functionality that you need in your method.
If you need to be able to access a certain element in the collection by using an indexer, an `ICollection<T>` would not be a good choice as an argument type for your interface, since `ICollection<T>` does not define such an indexer.

**Q2 & Q3:**

It's all about abstraction and the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

When you have a method which accepts an `IEnumerable` for instance, you can assign an `IReadonlyCollection` to it, because it implements IEnumerable next to `IEnumerable<T>`.  If it would only implement `IEnumerable<T>`, then you would not be able to use assign an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` as an argument to a method which accepts an argument of type `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Sorry I dont get it. Can you post a sample code where I can use ICollection<T> and CANNOT use List<T>?

Comment: @monstro Any container type that doesn't support index-access will be an `ICollection` but not an `IList` - examples are linked lists, hashmaps, etc.

Comment: @monstro That's the point, if you have code that can function with an IEnumerable, it can also function with an IList, so there's going to be no such example.

Comment: Q2 and Q3 aren't about LSP, it's just that the framework explicitly lists ALL interfaces that are being implemented. Not listing them wouldn't change _behavior_ at all. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160889/why-does-ilistt-implement-ienumerablet-and-icollectiont-while-icollection) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Making your code less specific makes it more powerful. Let's say you have a method like this:

```
void MyMethod(IList<int> items, int count, int start)
{
    while(items.Count < count)
    {
       items.Add(start++);
    }
}
```

The method asks for an `IList<int>`, does some List-y things, and then returns. However, the method does not do anything you couldn't also do with an `ICollection<int>`:

```
void MyMethod(ICollection<int> items, int count, int start)
{
    while(items.Count < count)
    {
       items.Add(start++);
    }
}
```

Which of these two methods is more powerful?

It may surprise you, but the answer is the second one. `IList<int>` implements `ICollection<int>`, and therefore you can still pass any `IList<int>` to the second method. However, you can't pass any `ICollection<int>` to the first method. Having the interfaces depend on each other in this way allows us to write methods that are just as specific as needed, and in this way make our code more powerful by allowing it to work with more types of object.

The only time you run into a situation where you want the more-specific type when you only need the less-specific operations is when working with a library written by a team that hasn't understood this yet.

As for why the documentation shows all of the different interface implementations, you'd have to ask the language designers, but I could guess that they just wanted to be explicit about this, and make it easier for those of us who need to read the documentation and verify that IList does indeed implement ICollection.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should define the meaning of **better**. `IList<T>` has more functionalities than `ICollection<T>`. But having more features is not always a better choice. Most of the time, it is better to use a type with least functionalities.

In this case having minimum functionality to satisfy the requirement is better. For example you may mention a collection type like `ConcurrentList` as a better option. Although it has more functionalities (great for concurrent manipulations), but it has also some performance pitfalls.

**Q2 & Q3:** For the repetitive interface declarations I think they're not necessary and they write them just for clarity.

Comment: I defined my "better" above as more powerful. So? Whats not good about it in my specific question? I want proof, not just words. Words I can find in MSDN. Also, what aboyt repetitive interface declarations?

Comment: @monstro In some situations it's **better** to pick a less powerful one.

Comment: @monstro About the repetitive interfaces, I think they're just for more clarity in the code

Comment: You defined your better as most powerful type? Then go `dynamic`...  the most powerfull type! @monstro

Comment: @mehrandvd: agree with your points. especially if I'm using my own custom classes. Why would I want to implement a full `IList<T>` when I'm only planning to use the minimal interfaces declared in `ICollection<T>`? It wouldn't make sense. So youre totally right.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick extension of Frederik's answer. Why one should always use the most generalized interface

```
public void Generalized(ICollection<string> collection)
{
    //blah
}

public void Specialized(List<string> collection)
{
    //blah
}

public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    ICollection<string> coll = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
    List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b" };

    Generalized(coll);
    Generalized(list);

    Specialized(list);
    Specialized(coll); //doesn't compile
}
```

And about the interface definition, they are there to make it more clear to an user what all they have with a `List<T>`.

**Edit**

To make it complete, it needs to be noted here, while returning and object from a method, it's always wise to return the most specialized one.

It all boils down to *assignment compatibility* and *re-usability*. As input, take the most generalized one so that everything else can be accepted. While returning, return the most specialized one so that it works for most of the calling methods.

```
public ICollection<string> ReturnGeneralized()
{
    return new List<string>();
}

public List<string> ReturnSpecialized()
{
    return new List<string>();
}

static void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    ICollection<string> coll1 = ReturnGeneralized();
    List<string> list1 = ReturnGeneralized(); //doesn't compile

    ICollection<string> coll2 = ReturnSpecialized();
    List<string> list2 = ReturnSpecialized();
}
```

So, the ideal method here, should look like

```
public List<string> MostUsable(IEnumerable<string> collection)
{
    return new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `List<T>` can do everything that `ICollection<T>` and much more.

Not really. The main difference between `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` is that the former is **unordered**, or let say it differently, the order of the elements is not defined by the interface. While the later provides additional functionality (indexed access), it at the same time it puts constraints on the containers that implement it (due to required list contract invariants). What does that mean - Add/Remove operations for list are highly inefficient (except at the end of the list and especially at the beginning of the list). From the other side, `ICollection<T>` does not have such constraints, so the containers have a freedom to implement the operations in a most efficient way. For instance, another popular class `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` but not `IList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. Is it less powerfull than `List<T>`? The answer is no. So far there is no single container that can perform all the operations effectively. Another example: searching `IList<T>` (`Contains`, `IndexOf`) is highly inefficient. Compare to `HashSet<T>` class implementation of `ICollection<T>` where `Contains`, `Add` and `Remove` are super fast. If it would have been forced to implement `IList<T>' (to make it more powerful by your logic) then the last 2 operations would suffer like in`List`.

> Why then in Code first tutorials they use `ICollection<T>`?

I guess you have in mind Entity Framework. Let think. The main purpose of the entities is to support effectively the 4 main db operations called CRUD (create, read, update, delete). As you may see, there is no indexed access (and in general, db tables are not like lists), so putting `IList<T>` constraint for the implementors of these operations does not make sense. From all standard interfaces `ICollection<T>` is closer to the **minimum** functionality needed by both clients and implementors. Note that nothing prevents you to **assign** `List<T>` to these EF navigation properties when you are populating the entity, but still allowing EF to use diferent container when they are populating the data from database for you.

To conclude, `IList<T>` is not suitable for all scenarios, that's why other interfaces that better suit for a specific scenario exist. `List<T>` is a **good** class, but **definitely not the best** - simply because such thing doesn't exist.

P.S. All the above applies of course to your **Q1**. What about **Q2** and **Q3** - it's just a matter of taste. Same as some people use optional features like **explicit** `private` for class fields, `internal` for class, `this.` when accessing class members etc., while other don't. The result is one and the same.